# skip header line and replace string in text file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off     
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion    
for /r %f in (xis_a*) do  More +1 %~nxf >> No_header_%~nxf    
set "search=:20:"

    set "replace={:20:"
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type (No_header_*.txt) ^& break ^> (No_header_*.txt) ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>No_header_*.txt echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
```

am trying to skip the header line in a text file and replace :20: with {:20:. i have written and have achieved almost.. please try to help me am totally new to this

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
set "search=:20:"
set "replace={:20:"

for /r "%sourcedir%" %%f in (xis_a*) do (
 REM DEL "%destdir%\No_header_%%~nf.txt" >NUL 2>nul
 for /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%i in ("%%f") do (
  set "line=%%i"
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
  >>"%destdir%\No_header_%%~nf.txt" echo(!line!
  ENDLOCAL
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should solve the problem.

In your code, the initial `setlocal` is establishing the default condition, so I omitted it.

You have `%f` in your `'for /r` - the `%` before the metavariable `f` needs to be doubled.

The `more` ceremony isn't required - `for /f` has a `skip` option which will allow the first n lines to be skipped.

So - all that is required is to get the list of files generated by the `for...%%f...` loop and with each, process each individual file, skipping the first line. Quoting the filename appearing in `%%f` is simply a safety-measure to allow for filenames containing separators, but this means that `usebackq` needs to be invoked to tell `for /f` that the list given is not a literal string (which it will assume for a "quoted string,") but a filename.

Then, since `%%f` is in-context for the `%%i` loop, you can select the target filename by using `%%~nf`. I'm not sure whether you want `~nf` or `~nxf` (adding a second `.txt` extension) so I elected to use `~n` alone. Note that your use of `*` is doomed - that means "all files matching" - probably not quite what you want, and `cmd` will get very confused.

I've aded a remmed-out `del` command to allow the destination file to be deleted - just remove the `rem` if required, otherwise the data will be appended to any exiating file.

I use my `u:` drive for testing, and have left my source and destination names in place. No doubt you would need to change those to suit your system.

Comment: So `"usebackqskip=1delims="` works without spaces in it but (other than at the end meaning no delims) why would you put it all together like that?  Seems hard for someone to learn from, but I'm learning all the time so...

Comment: @Torqane: Programmers are notoriously lazy - always looking for a shorter way. Minimise typing. It's quite possible that you could separate the various "keywords" with spaces or commas - even semicolons - in this case, the keywords must be unabbreviated and are quite distinct, so there appears to be no real reason to include superfluous separators.